# Returning Null Value for Unknown Type

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, null, nullable

I'm trying to write the following method using generics. (My actual method is more complex than this.)

```
public T ParseDictionaryItem<T>(string s, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary)
{
    T result;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out result))
        return result;
    // TODO: Return special value such as null to indicate invalid item
}
```

My goal is to return something like `null` if the item is not in the dictionary.

The problem is that I don't know what type `T` is. If `T` was an integer, for example, then I should return the type `T?`. However, if `T` is a class, then it is already nullable. And I won't know this until run time.

Can anyone see a clean way to return a special value in this method to indicate the item is invalid? I'm open to returning something other than `null`, but it has to be a special value. (0 is not a special value for integers.)

Comment: The best you can do is `default(T)`, but that won't be "unique" for an `int`.

Comment: The simplest is to create two overloads - one for class types and one for nullable structs. Alternatively create your own `Maybe<T>` type and return that.

Comment: Why doesn't the caller just use TryGetValue directly? It returns a bool indicating if the item is valid and an out parameter has the item, if valid. Or if the method is more complicated, at least something following that pattern.

Comment: @mikez: As I indicated in my question, my actual method is more complex than this. I simplified it to illustrate my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest returning a `ParseResult<T>`, which is defined as something like:

```
public struct ParseResult<T>
{
    // Or an exception, or a way of creating an exception
    private readonly bool success;
    private readonly T value;

    // Accessors etc
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about nullability, and you can make it *very* clear what you're doing. This is the pattern I've used in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) and to my mind it's worked very well. (Currently we use a class rather than a struct, but I might change that...)

I prefer it to other approaches because:

- It is clean to call, unlike using an `out` parameter
- It doesn't need ugly and potentially expensive try/catch handling
- It behaves *exactly* the same way whether `T` is a reference type or a value type
- It's flexible enough to represent the situation where `null` *is* a successful parse value
- You can still propagate the cause of a failure without throwing the exception when you don't need to

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about returning a class with additional information but was hoping for something lighter and simpler. But perhaps is this the best approach.

Comment: I find myself using this pattern more and more.

Comment: If only `Nullable` didn't have the constraint that the generic argument be a value type...

Comment: @Jon: Can I ask why you chose a `struct` over a class here?

Comment: @JonathanWood: Hard to say, exactly - particularly given that it's the opposite decision to that in Noda Time. It feels like it's a bit like `Nullable<T>`, really just decorating a "real" value. It's nice to avoid a heal allocation on every parse operation, too. It would certainly work with a class as well though.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps two overloads would help:

```
public T? ParseStructDictionaryItem<T>(string s, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary) where T : struct
{
    T result;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out result))
        return result;
    return null;
}

public T ParseReferenceDictionaryItem<T>(string s, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary) where T : class
{
    T result;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out result))
        return result;
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I know, they have different names.

Comment: Sorry, had just noticed that. Proceed.

Answer (score 4):

You can create two methods one for value types and another for reference type.
Value type method will return `T?` instead of `T`. In both of the methods, you can return `null` to indicate a invalid value.

```
public T? ParseDictionaryItemValueType<T>(string s, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary)
 where T : struct
{
    T result;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out result))
        return result;
    return null;
}

public T ParseDictionaryItemReferenceType<T>(string s, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary)
 where T : class
{
    T result;
    dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel? Take a look at your own code:
You are using the Dictionary's `TryGetValue` method. How does it handle the same issue?
I suggest you follow the footsteps of the .Net Framework developers and do the same:

```
public bool TryParseDictionaryItem<T>(string s, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary, out T result)
{
   if (dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out result)) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
```

}

**Update**
Since you don't like this approach, How about turning it on it's head?

```
public T TryParseDictionaryItem<T>(string s, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary, out bool Success)
{
   T result = default(T);
   Success = (dictionary.TryGetValue(s, out result)) 
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes I see that, but I didn't really like that approach. For one thing, `out` parameters cannot be class instance properties. And I find it more awkward.